# Removing NaN elements from a matrix

Tags: matlab

There is one NaN element per row, I want to remove it.

```
A=[NaN  1  2;  
    3  NaN 4;  
   NaN  5  6];
```

The desired output is:

```
[1 2;  
 3 4;  
 5 6]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
A = [NaN 1 2 ; 3 NaN 4; NaN 5 6]
sz = size(A);
B = reshape(A', size(A,1)*size(A,2), 1);
B(isnan(B)) = [];
B = reshape(B, sz(2)-1, sz(1))'
```

Comment: +1 vectorized.  But same caveat - must have at least one nan per row.

Answer (score 2):

I thought it could be done in one line, but I was wrong.  See solution below:

Given  (added row helps me debug my indexing below):

```
>> A = [NaN 1 2 ; 3 NaN 4; NaN 5 6; 7 8 NaN]
A =
   NaN     1     2
     3   NaN     4
   NaN     5     6
     7     8   NaN
```

Then:

```
>> Atrans = A';
>> B = reshape(    Atrans(~isnan(Atrans))    ,[],size(Atrans,2))'
B =
     1     2
     3     4
     5     6
     7     8
```

---

Incidentally, the Matlab idiom of performing a simple logical check on an array within an logical indexing operation is very common and incredibly useful.  The archetypical example is:

```
>> x(x>0)   %This returns a 1D column vector of all values of x 
            %which are greater than 0, regardless of the initial
            %size of x.  Multidimensional inputs are unwrapped 
            %column-first
```

Everything else above is size and dimension handling.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is - please note that the code is not robust. It assumes that indeed in every row there is a `NaN` element.

While it is not a vectorized solution, it has other advantages - like a clear code.

```
for i=1:size(A,1)
   x = A(i,:);
   x(isnan(x)) = [];
   B(i,:) = x;
end
```

> B
>
> B =
>
> ```
> 1     2
> 3     4
> 5     6
> ```

Comment: Are you sure, your code does, what the question was asking for? `A(isnan(A))=[]` returns column-wise array of `A`. When applying `reshape` (note the syntax error with `sz(A,.)`) it finally swaps the first elements of the first and second row.