# Removing nan elements from matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, nan

I have a bunch of matrices `eq1`, `eq2`, etc. defined like

```
from numpy import meshgrid, sqrt, arange
# from numpy import isnan, logical_not

xs = arange(-7.25, 7.25, 0.01)
ys = arange(-5, 5, 0.01)
x, y = meshgrid(xs, ys)

eq1 = ((x/7.0)**2.0*sqrt(abs(abs(x)-3.0)/(abs(x)-3.0))+(y/3.0)**2.0*sqrt(abs(y+3.0/7.0*sqrt(33.0))/(y+3.0/7.0*sqrt(33.0)))-1.0)

eq2 = (abs(x/2.0)-((3.0*sqrt(33.0)-7.0)/112.0)*x**2.0-3.0+sqrt(1-(abs(abs(x)-2.0)-1.0)**2.0)-y)
```

where `eq1`, `eq2`, `eq3`, etc. are large square matrices. As you can see, there are many `nan` elements surrounding a 'block' of plot-able values. I want to remove all the `nan` values whilst keeping the shape of the block of the valid values in the matrix. Note that these 'blocks' can be located anywhere in the `eq1`, `eq2` matrix.

I've looked at answers given in [Removing nan values from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620914/removing-nan-values-from-an-array) and [Removing NaN elements from a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922057/removing-nan-elements-from-a-matrix), but these don't seem to be completely relevant to my case.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"?

Comment: "remove" as in take out `nan` and leave the non-`nan` values as they are in the matrix ... kind of like cutting off all the crusts when you're making a sandwich.

Comment: `sqrt(abs(abs(x)-3.0)/(abs(x)-3.0))` - why would you do this? The values of the array inside the sqrt are always 1, -1, or NaN.

Comment: the matrices I get from inputting your sample code are not square

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use boolean indexing with `np.isnan` to keep the slices.  There are probably slicker ways to do this, but starting from something like:

```
>>> eq = np.zeros((5,6)) + np.nan
>>> eq[2:4, 1:3].flat = [1,np.nan,3,4]
>>> eq
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,   1.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,   3.,   4.,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

You could select the rows and columns with data using something like

```
>>> eq = eq[:,~np.isnan(eq).all(0)]
>>> eq = eq[~np.isnan(eq).all(1)]
>>> eq
array([[  1.,  nan],
       [  3.,   4.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Short and sweet,

```
eq1_c = eq1[~np.isnan(eq1)]
```

`np.isnan` returns a bool array that can be used to index your original array.  Take its negation and you will get back the non-nan values.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. I just get a single array. It doesn't preserve the shape of the matrix that contains all the non-`nan` values.

Comment: yes, i see.  what do you want to happen if you're non-NaN values don't form a square matrix? Or in other words, what if your NaN values don't form a cross in the original matrix?  More generally, this might be a question of how do you identify square blocks of `True` in a bool matrix

Answer (score 0):

One option is to manually iterate through the grid and check for Nan values. A Nan value is easy to spot because comparing it to itself will result in False. You could use this to set all Nan values to 0.0 for example.

```
for x in xrange(len(eq1)):
    for y in xrange(len(eq1[x])):
        v = eq1[x][y]
        if v!=v:
            eq1[x][y] = 0.0
```